# Shove a delimited string into a List<int>

Tags: c#, string, parsing

If I have for example the following string:

"123;3344;4334;12"

and I want these numbers in a generic `List<int>`, I guess I don't know of a good way here other than to split in a loop and do a conversion then add to a `List<int>` through each iteration.  Does anyone have other ways to go about this?

Updated.  Here's what I came up with.  I want to do this the old fashion way, not with LINQ because I'm trying to get better with just strings, arrays, lists and manipulating and converting in general.

```
public List<int> StringToList(string stringToSplit, char splitDelimiter)
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToSplit))
        return list;

    string[] values = stringToSplit.Split(splitDelimiter);

    if (values.Length <= 1)
        return list;

    foreach (string s in values)
    {
        int i;
        if (Int32.TryParse(s, out i))
            list.Add(i);
    }

    return list;
}
```

This is a new string utility method I plan on using whenever I need to convert a delimited string list to List

So I'm returning an empty list back to the caller if something fails.  Good/Bad?  is it pretty common to do this?

Yes, there are more "elegant" ways to do this with LINQ but I want to do it manually..the old way for now just for my own understanding.

Also, what bothers me about this:

```
list.AddRange(str.Split(';').Select(Int32.Parse));
```

is that I have no idea:

1. How to shove in a TryParse there instead.
2. What if the `str.Split(';').Select(Int32.Parse)` just fails for whatever reason...then the method that this AddRange resides in is going to blow up and unless I add a try/catch around this whole thing, I'm screwed if I don't handle it properly.

Comment: Using TryParse here is a serious mistake: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIGO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string str = "123;3344;4334;12";
List<int> list = new List<int>();

foreach (string s in str.Split(';'))
{
    list.Add( Int32.Parse(s));
}
```

Comment: +1, you read the title! I would suggest using TryParse instead of Parse.

Comment: I wounder if you can just do List<int> list = "123;3344;4334;12".Split(";");  I know you can with an array: string[] list = "123;3344;4334;12".Split(";");

Comment: @coffee, no.  You can't implicitly convert from an array of strings to a `List<int>`.  Also, it should be `Split(';')`.  Note the single quote, because it's a character literal.

Comment: So if TryParse fails, then null is added?  If you've got list.Add(tryparse...) and the parse fails is something still added to the list?

Comment: Didn't the OP say "other than to split in a loop and do a conversion then add to a List<int>"?

Comment: @coffeeaddict, you can't do `list.Add(int.TryParse...` when working with a list of ints because `TryParse` returns a bool. If it fails, `null` does not get added, `false` does (and `true` on success).

Answer (score 6):

```
static int? ToInt32OrNull(string s)
{
    int value;
    return (Int32.TryParse(s, out value)) ? value : default(int?);      
}
// ...
var str = "123;3344;4334;12"; 
var list = new List<int>();
list.AddRange(str.Split(';')
                 .Select(ToInt32OrNull)
                 .Where(i => i != null)
                 .Cast<int>());
```

Questioner notes:

> I don't know of a good way here other than to split in a loop and do a conversion then add to a List

In general, this is a major reason why LINQ was brought into C# - to remove the need to work with sequences of values by implementing loops, and instead just declare your intention to transform the sequence. If you ever find yourself thinking "I don't know how to do this except with a loop" - it's time to look into a LINQ construct which will do the work for you.

**Performance Update:**

Performance of LINQ has been quesioned below. While in the comments the idea of LINQ being slower is defended since we gain the benefits of readability, maintainability and composibility, there is another aspect which gives LINQ an easy performance advantage: parallelism. Here is an example where adding just one extension method call, `AsParallel()` doubles the performance. This is a great example of where scale-out beats micro-optimization without even needing to measure very carefully. Note I'm not claiming that micro-optimizations are not ever needed, but with the tools we have available at this level of absraction, the need becomes vanishingly small.

```
class Program
{
    private const int ElementCount = 10000000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var str = generateString();
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        var list1 = new List<int>(ElementCount); 
        var list2 = new List<int>(ElementCount);

        var split = str.Split(';');

        stopwatch.Start();
        list1.AddRange(split
                          .Select(ToInt32OrNull) 
                          .Where(i => i != null) 
                          .Cast<int>());
        stopwatch.Stop();

        TimeSpan nonParallel = stopwatch.Elapsed;

        stopwatch.Restart();

        list2.AddRange(split
                          .AsParallel()
                          .Select(ToInt32OrNull)
                          .Where(i => i != null)
                          .Cast<int>());

        stopwatch.Stop();

        TimeSpan parallel = stopwatch.Elapsed;

        Debug.WriteLine("Non-parallel: {0}", nonParallel);
        Debug.WriteLine("Parallel: {0}", parallel);
    }

    private static String generateString()
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder(1048576);
        var rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < ElementCount; i++)
        {
            builder.Append(rnd.Next(99999));
            builder.Append(';');
        }

        builder.Length--;

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    static int? ToInt32OrNull(string s)
    {
        int value;
        return (Int32.TryParse(s, out value)) ? value : default(int?);
    } 
}
```

> Non-parallel: 00:00:07.0719911
>
> Parallel: 00:00:04.5933906

Comment: yea I wonder on performance vs. the standard split in a loop though

Comment: @coffeeaddict: It's almost always negligable, and it should only be considered for change if it is measured and found to be a problem. Here's a good, recent comparison: http://jerrytech.blogspot.com/2010/02/revisiting-c-loop-performance.html

Comment: I don't know I always here you can overuse LINQ also in that it can start to be a peformance hog.  Not saying you're wrong...yea

Comment: shouldn't we also be checking that there is an empty string first?

Comment: I wonder though if the Parse fails then what, you get an exception.  So you'd have to wrap this in a try/catch and handle it so that you don't halt your application.  Furthermore if I took yours and tried to add TryParse, how would that fit in that statement?

Comment: I've had the same issues, which I've dealt with in my own way. I'll update the answer so you can see if you like it...

Comment: You're a pretty lucky programmer if youre biggest performance concern is a string split function. I don't believe LINQ has any significant overhead over foreach loops, it's just easy for naive programmers to lose track of their big O complexity when they don't see nesting.

Comment: Um, I disagree, it depends on context and application.  I work for a .com that gets 2 million hits a month.  Performance is everything and it adds up throughout the application.  So wherever you can tweak for performance ALWAYS teak for performance.  I'm not a pro at performance but I do know one thing is that you should always consider it no matter how "trivial" of an action you're performing because overall together it will have a large impact.  Or, if I were to work for a trading firm, performance concerns to this degree is commonplace.

Comment: @coffeeaddict, I disagree entirely with your position on optimization, as I'm sure most other developers would. Sure, performance might be everything, but guessing where the performance hit will be should NOT be done up front, and you'll invariably get it wrong, ending up with opaque code that could be much clearer. Design well, code clearly, then only optimize when a problem shows up.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: sorry, but I disagree. Even at that scale, code readability and maintainability trump milliseconds, especially when it is so cheap to scale out.

Comment: I'm not saying not to use LINQ, but you have to question how things work behind the elegance and should always analyze and check things out.  Sometimes the elegance is counteractive on bringing down performance.

Comment: "code readability and maintainability trump milliseconds"  Not when you need a page to load for 2 million users under 2 seconds.

Comment: "guessing where the performance hit will be should NOT be done up front"  I don't understand where you get guessing from.  I just "wondered" and need to find out because using too much LINQ can be devastating to performance in certain ways...I don't know what that is right now as I don't know LINQ enough but definitely I've seen many developers tell me to be careful just how much LINQ is all over your application and to balance the amount of LINQ you put in.

Comment: Also, I wonder about the return statements.  Isn't it good practice and just easier to debug when you're returning value and not return [this whole huge line of code]; ?

Comment: How are you able to put in default() here, just curious?  Never seen that done except in a case statement.

Comment: @coffeeaddict -  "Not when you need a page to load for 2 million users under 2 seconds." I'd say, yes, even then. From what I understand, there is another large .COM, Google.com, which implements a protocol called "Map/Reduce" which is, in essence, using declarative over imperative syntax. Given that they are a major destination on the internet, perhaps with even more than 2M hits / mo, yet code in a fashion which leaves performance to scale, you might reconsider your perspective. The reason is with declarative code, you can leave performance to the platform.

Comment: @coffeeaddict - Also note that I'm not advocating ignorance of the implementation: abstractions leak, and understanding the performance implications of something is important. However, given that choice of algorithm or data-management or access strategy often overwhelms any micro-performance benefit, micro-perf really shouldn't be the first thing to consider. As the renound author on software engineering, Michael Jackson, stated in his first rule on opimization: don't. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization

Comment: @coffeeaddict - default(T) can be used anywhere a value of type T is expected.

Comment: @codekaizen I will refrain from debating this...it's one of those never-ending debates with no end in sight if you know what I mean ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
List<int> list = (from numString in "123;3344;4334;12".Split(';') 
                  select int.Parse(numString)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string myString = "123;3344;4334;12";
var ints = new List<int>();
(from s in myString.Split(';')
 select int.Parse()).ToList().ForEach(i=>ints.Add(i));
```

I've heard .Net 4.0 may have added `ForEach` to `Enumerable<T>`, so the `ToList` might be unnecessary there (can't test).

Comment: After the `ToList`, you *have* a list of ints.  The `ForEach` is unneeded.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen, agreed. My initial (and admittedly hurried) initial thought was the list might not be original and the contents might need to be preserved. i.e. append the results to an existing list without replacement.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is simplest

```
  var str = "123;3344;4334;12"; 
  var list = str.Split(';').ToList().Cast<int>();
```

Comment: -1: This never works, cause you can't cast a string to an integer. You can only parse it (using `int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()`).